# reverse the order of CategoricalDtype in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, categorical-data

I have an ordered categorical variable in my dataframe like the following:

```
CategoricalDtype(categories=['UNDER $1 000', '$1 000 TO 2 999', '$3 000 TO 3 999', 
                              '$90000 - $109999', '$110000 OR OVER', 'REFUSED'], 
                               ordered=True)
```

For `CategoricalIndex` in a dataframe I know I can do the following:

`df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)`

I tried the method I find [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.sort.html#pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.sort) for the `CategoricalDtype` object:

```
from pandas import Categorical
Categorical.sort(ascending=False)
```

but it doesn't work and returned:

`AttributeError: type object 'Categorical' has no attribute 'sort'.`

Thus, I wonder if there is an easy way to reverse the order for `CategoricalDtype` with Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list slicing / NumPy array syntax, i.e. `[::-1]`, to reverse the order. This is natural because `dtype.categories` returns a `pd.Index` object, which has an underlying NumPy array.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

dtype = CategoricalDtype(categories=['UNDER $1 000', '$1 000 TO 2 999', '$3 000 TO 3 999',
                                     '$90000 - $109999', '$110000 OR OVER', 'REFUSED'],
                         ordered=True)

dtype_reversed = CategoricalDtype(categories=dtype.categories[::-1], ordered=True)

# CategoricalDtype(categories=['REFUSED', '$110000 OR OVER', '$90000 - $109999',
#                   '$3 000 TO 3 999', '$1 000 TO 2 999', 'UNDER $1 000'],
#                  ordered=True)
```

Comment: Your solution indeed seems more clear to me, but it seems performs much slower than @wes solution using `reversed()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for a `CategoricalIndex` object with the reversed list of categories, you might consider creating a new object with the reversed list of categories from your original instance.

if `x` is your existing `CategoricalDtype` object:

```
x_reversed = CategoricalDtype(categories=reversed(x.categories), ordered=True)
```

Comment: I found a way to sort the index before seeing your answer and updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered another way to do it.

Since `CategoricalDtype` in `pandas` has an [attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#categorical) `cat.categories`, we can call it from a variable right away and reserve its order directly by using `reversed()` or `[::-1]`. If a pandas `Series` is categorical, `pandas` also offers lots of [methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.set_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.set_categories) like `cat.set_categories`. Thus, for a variable named `var` in the dataframe, we can do the following:

```py
order = df.var.cat.categories[::-1]
df.var.cat.set_categories(new_categories=order, ordered=True, inplace=True)
```

By using this method, we don't have to create a `CategoricalDtype` object or importing anything. It also saves us from using `.astype()` to replace the old order in the categorical variable as well.